# How to query for overlapping date ranges?

Tags: django, django-models

I have members who are for a limited time assigned to a team. Members can be assigned to multiple teams. The members create worklogs on a day. Worklogs are assigned to a member, the member is assigned to a team. The intermediate table Membership stores the assignment dates of team members.

I need to query all worklogs related to a specific team during e.g. the first quarter of 2019. The team members could've joined and left during the quarter and only the worklogs during their team assignment should be considered.

```
class Teamuser(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Team(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Teamuser, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    memberid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    teamuser = models.ForeignKey(Teamuser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateFrom = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    dateTo = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class Worklog(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Teamuser, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    day = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    effort = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.TextField(null=True)
```

I tried to get first a list of all the users that were assigned during the time frame.

```
start = date(2019,1,10) 
end = date(2019,1,20) 
Teamuser.objects.filter(Q(membership__team_id=305), Q(membership__dateFrom__range=[start, end]) | Q(membership__dateTo__range=[start, end]) | Q(membership__dateFrom=None) | Q(membership__dateTo=None))
```

However, this does not include people that joined a team before the querying date and left afterwards. People with no dateFrom and dateTo are always in the team.

My biggest challenge at the moment is to figure out on which dates the two date ranges (Query for Q1, Memberships of a Teamuser) overlap

I expect an output of all Worklogs a Teamuser created during the timeframe (Q1 2019) while being assigned to the queried team (e.g. only January 2019).

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated my question.

Comment: Is it the case that one `Teamuser` could conceivably have more than one membership in the time period considered, e.g. member in January, assigned elsewhere in February, then member again from March onwards?

Comment: Exactly, that could be the case. My biggest challenge at the moment is to figure out on which dates the two date ranges (Query for Q1, Memberships of a Teamuser) overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you the users who were team members at some point in the time period considered:

```
teamusers = (Teamuser.objects
    .filter(
        Q(membership__dateTo__gte=start) | Q(membership__dateTo=None),
        Q(membership__dateFrom__lte=end) | Q(membership__dateFrom=None),
        membership__team_id=305, 
    )
    .distinct()
)
```

This filters for end dates that are null, greater than or equal to the period start, and start dates that are null, lower than or equal to the end date.

But this is at most useful to pre-filter the work log, as you cannot just take the logs of all members in the list in the time period considered and be done with it. You might have work logs that the users posted outside their membership dates.

So you'll have to start from the log table, prefiltering it for the period in question and possibly for the team member list calculated above if you determine that it increases performance.

```
worklogs = Worklog.objects.filter(day__range=[start, end], worker__in=teamusers)
```

Then you use a subquery to check in every record whether the user who posted it was a member of the team on that particular date:

```
from django.db.models import Q, OuterRef, Exists

membership_subquery = Teamuser.objects.filter(
    Q(membership__dateTo__gte=OuterRef('day')) | Q(membership__dateTo=None),
    Q(membership__dateFrom__lte=OuterRef('day')) | Q(membership__dateFrom=None),
    membership__team_id=305,
    teamuser=OuterRef('worker'), 
)

worklogs = (worklogs
    .annotate(in_team=Exists(membership_subquery))
    .filter(in_team=True)
)
```

Now you have a list of all valid work logs, and you can append further processing, like annotating aggregates etc.

Comment: Thanks! This worked and brings correct results, and helped me to get the right filters for the other solution. On my dataset the other solution seemed a little faster.

Comment: This is the correct answer.
However, the first arguments in the filter have to be wrapped in `Q()`, too. And the subquery should not compare to `start` and `end` but to `OuterRef('day')`.

Comment: Thanks, I had the OuterRefs first, then I pasted a simplified version from the first query and forgot to add them back. As to the filter clauses, you are right, you either have to wrap all of them in Qs, or you have to put the keyword arguments after the Q objects. I've amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way which seems working:

```
start=date(2019, 1, 1)
end=date(2019, 1, 31)

Worklog.objects.filter(
        Q(worker__membership__team_id=305), 
        Q(day__range=[start, end]), 
        Q(day__range=[F('worker__membership__dateFrom'),  F('worker__membership__dateTo')]) |  
        Q(worker__membership__dateFrom=None) | 
        Q(worker__membership__dateTo=None)
    )
```

Basically limiting on the day in the membership and in the query period.
I did not know about `F()` objects before, that was the key.

Still figuring out if it covers all the cases.

**Update:**

This works and shows correct results, I included the correct filter based on the input of Endre Both, below. That solutions works too, but feels a little slower on my rather small dataset. I did not measure times.

```
Worklog.objects.filter(
        Q(worker__membership__team_id=305), 
        Q(day__range=[start, end]), 
        Q(worker__membership__dateFrom=None) | Q(worker__membership__dateFrom__lte=end),
        Q(worker__membership__dateTo=None) | Q(worker__membership__dateTo__gte=start),
    )
```

Comment: This misses users who have one null and one non-null date (e.g. they joined at some point and are still a member of the team). Other than that, it seems to be a valid approach that does several joins instead of using a subquery; with large tables, the joins can get expensive.

Comment: You can test whether both approaches yield the same results and how long they take.